# Packing three increasing integers into one

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming

I have three integers representing positions on a board. Because all pieces are equal, the order does not matter, so it suffices to only consider increasing lists of three integers.

However I am having trouble finding a constant-time expression that encodes three integers in [0, n) as one integer with *minimal range*.

For two integers this formula would work. How can I generalize it?

$$a * n + b - \frac{a*(a+1)}{2}$$

Another problem that seems almost equivalent is how I can rotate and mirror the playing field to eliminate duplicate positions.

I have tried to find information on the internet about problems like these. Is there a name for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula that maps the triples of increasing 
numbers $0\le x <y<z<n$ to the set of numbers from $0$ to $\frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(n-2)-1$ is the following:

$$
\frac{x^3}{6}-\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)x^2+\left(\frac{(n-2)^2}{2}-\frac{1}{6}\right)x-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{2n-3}{2}y+z-n
$$

For example, for $n=6$, we have
$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
x & y & z & f(x,y,z)\\\hline
 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 & 5 & 3 \\
 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 0 & 2 & 4 & 5 \\
 0 & 2 & 5 & 6 \\
 0 & 3 & 4 & 7 \\
 0 & 3 & 5 & 8 \\
 0 & 4 & 5 & 9 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 10 \\
 1 & 2 & 4 & 11 \\
 1 & 2 & 5 & 12 \\
 1 & 3 & 4 & 13 \\
 1 & 3 & 5 & 14 \\
 1 & 4 & 5 & 15 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 16 \\
 2 & 3 & 5 & 17 \\
 2 & 4 & 5 & 18 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 19 \\
\end{array}
$$
where 
$$
f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^3}{6}-2x^2+\frac{47}{6}x-\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{9}{2}y+z-6.
$$

If the requirement is that the numbers are not-decreasing, i.e. 
$ 0\le x\le y \le z<n$, then the function that associates univocally a triple $(x,y,z)$ to a number in the from $0$ to $n (n + 1) (n + 2)/6-1$ is the following
$$
\frac{x^3-3nx^2+(3n^2-1)x-3y^2+(3n-3)y}{6}+z
$$

Comment: That is a complicated formula. No wonder I couldn't see it. Did you derive it from summations?

Comment: One more thing. Your formula is for strictly increasing sequences. Mine can have the same integer twice.

Comment: @Joonazan I added the formula for the case of non-decreasing triplets. Once I figured the formula could be expressed as a cubic in $x$ plus a quadratic in $y$ plus $z$, I simply found the explicit formulas by fitting the values for small values of $n$. Then I deduced the general format of the coefficients of $x$ and $y$. I could have used the more analytic way, but I'm lazy and you just asked for a result not a proof.